# How to save the font size in a <span> or <run> in a RichtextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm using Richtextbox C# control in a program that acts as a notepad,
 I'm trying to save my font size in a span or run because I'm saving my content using XAML reader/writer so I want to force my font size to be in the run of the document. Is there anyway I can do that?

Is there anyway I can save these information inside the RTB or the Flow Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Application Settings, more information Here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh(v=VS.100).aspx

Regards

Comment: That's perfect if I want to have the same font and size for all the document, but what if I want to have different font settings in the document, like each word can have different font size.